# I want to publish my first Facebook application and a Privacy Policy URL is required

Tags: android

I want to publish my first application and a Privacy Policy URL is required.

I have the page privacypolicy.html published in my website but I get the following message when I configure it in "App Details":

> You must submit a valid Privacy Policy URL in order to be compliant
>   with Facebook Platform. Request failed with error: Bad Response Code:
>   URL returned a bad HTTP response code.

Comment: Maybe a missing `http://` or a mistyped URL? The error message seems pretty clear to me. Try copying the adress you entered and pasting it in a browser to see if it is spelled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You must Add URL on Privacy Section. It's Google's Policy. You can host your privacy policy with any publicly accessible URL .

Read official guideline about [Privacy Policy](https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/privacy-policy-guide)

you can create your own site by [Create here](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/6372878?ref_topic=6372877)